# A campus population consists of 70% students, 20% staff and 10% faculty (ignoring visitors)....

Tags: probability

A campus population consists of 70% students, 20% staff and 10% faculty (ignoring visitors). Of these three components, 10% of students park on campus, 65% of staff park on campus, and 75% of faculty park on campus.

a) What is the probability that a member of the campus population parks on campus?

b) For a car parked on campus, what is the probability that it belongs to a faculty member?

I just wanted to make sure that what I have is correct. :)

a) (.10)(.70) + (.65)(.20) + (.75)(.10) = (.275).
b) (.75)(.10) = (.075).

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Part a is fine.  However, I believe that for part b you want to find the probability that given the car was on campus, it belonged to faculty.  The answer you give is faculty And car parked.  You need to take your answer and divide by your answer in a.

Comment: @MaggieMyers Sorry, I wrote the question wrong (I've corrected it). Now b should be correct, right?

Comment: I figured you wrote it wrong.  However, for a car parked on campus means the same as given a car is parked on campus so it should be a conditional.  You are restricting to knowing the car was on campus.

Comment: Maggie Myers is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the division rule for part b) where $P(A|B) = {P(A,B)\over P(B)}$